# Wordpress overriding actual subdirectories

Tags: redirect

I have a site driven by Wordpress and a few custom directories that I've got at the top level.  Some of these top-level directories work and the content inside of them are being read as expected.

However, I've just created a new folder directory with an index.html inside and when I try to visit it, Wordpress is overriding it and displaying a 404 error (since that directory structure doesn't exist in the Wordpress database).

I've disabled the W3 cache and I've checked the .htaccess file in the event that I put in a redirect in the past, but nothing that would indicate a redirect back to Wordpress.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess and the directory name (at least relative to your content root)? Also, are you using Apache or IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress tries to be transparent for physical files and folders. So either something gets broken at server configuration level or at WP rewrites level.

The first things to check in such cases would be disabling pretty permalinks and if there might be come paths generated by WP that conflict with that specific folder name.