# Run A Pre-Built Core PHP Application Under A WordPress Page or Post Route

Tags: php, api, routing, outside-wordpress

I have a complete application built in Core PHP and a WordPress site which has stable traffic every month, I need to get this new business application up and running under mysite.com/support. The problem is that, this URL will be read as a WordPress post URL and will try to look for a post with the slug "support", instead I want it to run the index.php of a seperate folder, within the root of the wordpress site and run it as an independent site completely out of WordPress. Then I will make sure it will have similar looks and feel and make sure the menu has ways to link back.

Is there a way to do this? That fastest one at that.

Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: This will help you http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40

Comment: Please add your answer and accept it.