# Does wordpress prevent non wordpress pages from being allowed on the same domain?

Tags: customization

I have built a landing page that consists of 3 php pages, css,js files. Is it possible to add these to a new page on my current domain

example.com/newfile1.php

I would like to do this with out relying on a sub domain to accomplish this however this is my first time working with the WordPress CMS so im not sure how restrictive WP is.

I suppose it might be worth mentioning that the clients site was built with something called Headway Themes again I don't know if this matters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot access non-wordpress subdirectories as wordpress overrides them with a 404 error](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40)

Comment: Normally you can have php files within WordPress with no problem at all. Are you having problems or just asking if you can do it? If you are having problems, please describe them.

Answer (score 1):

The WordPress way of doing it would be to simply create your pages within the WordPress dashboard and create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) to use for these landing pages.

However if you don't want to use WordPress (for whatever reason) the safest way would be to place the landing page in it's own directory so you would have `http://www.example.com/landingpage/newfile1.php` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this, particularly if it was in a sub folder, but I'm really not sure why you would not just integrate it within WP.

There is a real risk of clashing with pages that are created within WP and its really not a good idea.

Comment: The landing page was built with bootstrap. When I say they are php pages I mean there is a php script running to support a contact form and the files have a php extension. The rest of the page is pure html with some external JS files. 

Would I be able to do integrate this in WP with out rewriting then entire landing page?

@user3193817

Answer (score 0):

Put the files into their own subdirectory in your site and then in your .htaccess (or whatever similar equivalent your server stack uses) tell the server (and thus WordPress) not to rewrite the URLs for that subdirectory.

This tells the server and WordPress not to interpret requests for that subdirectory as WordPress "requests".