# Will Wordpress installed on a whole domain interfere with other files in a subdomain or subfolder?

Tags: subdomains

If I install WordPress at `[mydomain.com]` - a domain that I keep hosted somewhere other than at Wordpress.com - will it interfere with any files I keep

- either on a dedicated subdomain (e.g. a bulletin board at `forum.[mydomain].com`)
- or in a subfolder (e.g. a collection of documents at `[mydomain].com/documents`)?

I suspect the answer to the first part is "no", but I am not so sure about the second part, concerning the subfolder. I would like to save and remove files at `[mydomain].com/documents` using FTP, and create other subfolders such as `[mydomain].com/whatever`, without any relationship to or interference from WordPress or from what I do using Wordpress elsewhere on my site, but is that possible?

Comment: The answer to this will depend almost exclusively on how your server is setup on the Nginx/Apache level. There is no PHP/WP level answer to this, however most of the time it is not an issue. You're going to have to heavily update your question to include Nginx or Apache vhost and htaccess files you intend to use in order for this question to be answerable

Comment: I found [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20152/cannot-access-non-wordpress-subdirectories-as-wordpress-overrides-them-with-a-40ErrorDocument), to which one answer says that writing `ErrorDocument 401 default` at the top  of `.htaccess` should keep Wordpress's hands off of non-WP subdirectories when it's installed at root. But unfortunately there's no explanation.